# Awk multiple columns of top

Tags: bash, awk, newline, eol

On RedHat, using this command (top ten cpu users):

```
top -n 1 -b -c|head -17|tail -11
```

I would only need the PID, USER, %CPU, %MEM, TIME+, & COMMAND columns

Ideally, I would like tabs between the first columns then the COMMAND column printing normally with space delimiters.

So, something similar to:

```
top -n 1 -b -c|head -17|tail -11|awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$9"\t"$10"\t"$11"\t"} {for (i=12;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s ",$i)} {print ""}'
```

However, a newline occurs between the two print statements.

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT:**

```
PID     USER    %CPU    %MEM    TIME+     COMMAND
15968   root    17.8    0.0     0:00.11   /usr/local/bin/pmun -p -h vm21fc root
15962   igsg093 16.2    0.1     0:00.16   top -n 1 -b -c
15966   idig056 6.5     0.1     0:00.04   /usr/bin/perl -w /scripts/script.pl arg
15969   root    6.5     0.1     0:00.04   pmasterd -ars
1       root    0.0     0.0     0:03.37   init [3]
2       root    0.0     0.0     3:38.62   [migration/0]
3       root    0.0     0.0     0:29.41   [ksoftirqd/0]
4       root    0.0     0.0     0:00.00   [watchdog/0]
5       root    0.0     0.0     0:03.70   [events/0]
6       root    0.0     0.0     0:00.00   [khelper]
```

**Any assistance would be appreciated.  Thanks!**

.

**BONUS help:**  If possible to cut the output of characters of the second print statement (for COMMAND) to a certain length, that may be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `OFS` (Output Field Separator) variable so that `print` handles the tabs for you:

```
top -n 1 -b -c| awk -vOFS="\t" 'NR>6 && NR<18 {s=""; for (i=12;i<=NF;++i) s=s FS $i; print $1,$2,$9,$10,$11,s}'
```

Comma separated arguments are printed with the OFS in between them.

If you would like to limit the length of `s`, you could take a `substr` of `s` in the print statement:

```
print $1,...,substr(s,0,N)
```

Where `N` is the maximum length of the the command.

Comment: Only problem here would be that the COMMAND section would only print the first space-delimited section of the program- technically the default of the top command except I added -c to get more.

Comment: @user2802708 just spotted that. I've just edited it so that the whole command is printed.

Comment: @user2802708 I've also shown how you can limit the length of the command string.

Comment: I modified it a little to fit formatting, and it looks great!  Thanks.

`top -n 1 -b -c|grep -v "top -n"| awk -vOFS="\t" 'NR>6 && NR<18 {s=""; for (i=12;i<=NF;++i) s=s FS $i; print $1,$2,$9,$10,$11"   ",substr(s,0,40)}'`

Answer (score 0):

Simply change this part: `{printf "%s", $1"\t"$2"\t"$9"\t"$10"\t"$11"\t"}`

You can also just skip head and tail:

```
top -n 1 -b -c| awk 'NR >= 7 && NR <= 17 {printf "%s", $1"\t"$2"\t"$9"\t"$10"\t"$11"\t"; for (i=12;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s ",$i); print ""}'
```